# What git commands do "hexo init <folder>" exactly do?

Tags: git, hexo

When I use **Hexo** [https://hexo.io/] to deploy a static blog on the github, at very first, I execute "hexo init " to initialize the hexo folder to generate files and folders like these:

.
├── _config.yml
├── package.json
├── scaffolds
├── source
|   ├── _drafts
|   └── _posts
└── themes

However When I execute command "hexo init ", I find it actually executes git commands:

```
  [root@localhost buwei]# hexo init blog
  INFO  Cloning hexo-starter to /home/buwei/blog
  Cloning into '/home/buwei/blog'...
  remote: Counting objects: 53, done.
  remote: Total 53 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 53
  Unpacking objects: 100% (53/53), done.
  Submodule 'themes/landscape' (https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-theme-      landscape.git) registered for path 'themes/landscape'
  ....
```

So I want to know what git commands do the "hexo init" execute?

Answer (score 2):

From [`hexojs/hexo-cli/lib/console/init.js#initConsole()`](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-cli/blob/9183375da4c9da6b806c86d3590f5078d0cebc79/lib/console/init.js#L27-L33), it mainly execute `git clone`:

```
  if (args.clone) {
    promise = spawn('git', ['clone', '--recursive', GIT_REPO_URL, target], {
      stdio: 'inherit'
    });
  } else {
    promise = copyAsset(target);
}
```

Then it removes the git dir (`.git`) and modules (`.gitmodules`)

```
  return promise.catch(function() {
    log.warn('git clone failed. Copying data instead');

    return copyAsset(target);
  }).then(function() {
    return Promise.all([
      removeGitDir(target),
      removeGitModules(target)
    ]);
  }).then(function() {
    if (!args.install) return;

    log.info('Install dependencies');

    return spawn('npm', ['install', '--production'], {
      cwd: target,
      stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`hexo init` is here to give you the main structure of the blog. If git command is available, it execute `git clone` of [hexo-starter](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-starter) repository, otherwise, hexo-cli make a copy of its [submodule - assets @ 221419b](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-cli) which contains sources of [hexo-starter](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-starter).